# Mysql stored procedure: Can't reopen table: 'temporary table'. How to solve this issue

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've successful execute this procedure when I call the stored procedure, I get error message:

> Can't reopen table: 'temp1'.

Its like temporary table used more than once in the query. Any ideas or other solution to solve this problem ?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE menu_t1()
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE if not exists temp1(
    object_id VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    display_name VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    menu_id VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    order_seq int NULL,
    menu_level int NULL,
    link_url VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    OrderString VARCHAR(200) NULL
    );

    insert into temp1 (object_id, description, display_name, menu_id, order_seq, menu_level, link_url, OrderString)
    SELECT mp.object_id, mp.description, mp.display_name, mp.menu_id, mp.order_seq, mp.menu_level, mp.link_url,
    concat('00',cast((mp.order_seq) as char)) OrderString 
    FROM ui_menuitem mp 
    WHERE mp.parent_id is null and mp.menu_id = '1';

    select * from temp1;

   select * from temp1
   union all
   select mc.object_id, mc.description, mc.display_name, mc.menu_id, mc.order_seq, mc.menu_level, mc.link_url, 
    concat(temp1.OrderString,'-',cast((mc.order_seq) as char)) OrderString
    from ui_menuitem mc, temp1
    where mc.parent_id = temp1.object_id and mc.menu_id = '1';

    TRUNCATE TABLE temp1;
   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;

COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This style looks like recursive.

Thanks

Comment: See documentation: `You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.` - [B.5.7.2 TEMPORARY Table Problems](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Did you have any ideas or solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

While you have declared the temporary table, you've not defined anything about it, such as columns, types, nor inserted any data into it.  All you've done is declare it, and then perform a select statement.

You need to instead define your table by doing something like this

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(
    object_id INT, 
    description VARCHAR(200)
    ...)
```

And then insert the data into it like this

```
INSERT INTO #temp1(object_id, description, ...)
SELECT mp.object_id, mp.description, ...
```

You are getting the error at present as temp1 currently has no OrderString column.

Comment: Hi Jonnus, thanks for your reply. I already modify the query as u said. This time i get error: Can't reopen table: 'temp1'. Where is the mistake this time?

Comment: Are you using the syntax "DROP TABLE #temp1" to remove your temporary tablet from memory?

Comment: Hi Jonuus. Yup i use DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1; at the end of my statement.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `#` prefix on temporary tables.